# what is this meaning:{ [productId: string]: ObjectType }?

Tags: typescript

I am studying typescript.below is some source code:

```
export class ShoppingCartItem{
  $key:string;
  title:string;
  imageUrl:string;
  price:number,
  quantity:number,
  }
......
......
  itemsMap: { [productId: string]: ShoppingCartItem };
```

what's the last line meaning({ [productId: string]: ShoppingCartItem })? It means itemsMap is a object?but...

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `itemsMap` is an object with keys always a string and the value is an instance of `ShoppingCartItem` class

Answer (score 0):

Its a mapping:
when the KEY is productId (type string, should be unique)
and the value is all the object.

you can get object by is poductId like:

```
const product = itemsMap[productId];
```

you can delete product:

```
delete itemsMap[productId];
```

you can update item by is productId:

```
itemsMap[productId] = ....
```